# Child with vertical scroll inside a parent with horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` with an horizontal scroll triggered with the mouse wheel. (Scrolling up or down with the wheel inside this element, will actually scroll left to right).

Inside this `div` I have another element with a vertical scroll.

Is it possible to trigger the scroll of the child element when the mouse is above, and then switch to the parent scroll (horizontal) when the child's scroll is finished ?

Comment: what's currently happening when the mouse pointer is directly over your vertically-scrollable child?

Comment: I can make two different situations:  scroll vertically in the child and the parent scroll doesn't work, or I can have the both scroll simultaneously.
But I would like the parent scroll to start only if the child's scroll is ended.

The parent scroll is handled this way :
`scrollLeft += event.deltaY + event.deltaX` where the event is a WheelEvent

Comment: if you manage how it's scrolled why can't use just read the state of the mouse buttons?

Comment: what do you mean with the state of the mouse buttons ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

I apologise if it does not work perfectly. I am on my Mac with a magic mouse

```js
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
const childDiv = document.getElementById('childDiv');

parentDiv.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  if (event.target === childDiv) {
    // Check if child is fully scrolled
    if ((childDiv.scrollHeight - childDiv.scrollTop === childDiv.clientHeight && event.deltaY > 0) ||
      (childDiv.scrollTop === 0 && event.deltaY < 0)) {
      // Scroll parent horizontally
      parentDiv.scrollLeft += event.deltaY;
    } else {
      // Scroll child vertically
      childDiv.scrollTop += event.deltaY;
    }
  } else {
    // Scroll parent horizontally
    parentDiv.scrollLeft += event.deltaY;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#parentDiv {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#childDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  /* Height more than childDiv to enable vertical scrolling */
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
  <!-- Child div with vertical scrolling -->
  <div id="childDiv">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
      <p>Content that can be scrolled vertically...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Additional content for horizontal scrolling -->
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 300px;">
    <p>More Content...</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 300px;">
    <p>Even More Content...</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 300px;">
    <p>Even More Content...</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 300px;">
    <p>Even More Content...</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 300px;">
    <p>Even More Content...</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 300px;">
    <p>Even More Content...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```